# Resample daily to annual from the most recent day?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date

I would like to convert the daily series to annual but to be based on the latest observation. For example, the latest observation is 2020-06-06 so I would like to convert to annual frequency from there (...2018-06-06, 2019-06-06, 2020-06-06). When I use the resample it automatically sets the annual series to the last calendar day of each year. Is there an easier way to do this or do I need to do further indexing to get these dates out?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
dates = pd.date_range('2010-01-01', today, freq='D')
np.random.seed(100)
 data = np.random.randn(len(dates))
 ts = pd.Series(data=data, index=dates, name='Series')
ts_year = ts.resample('A').ffill()
```

```
2010-12-31    0.790428
2011-12-31    1.518362
2012-12-31    0.150378
2013-12-31    0.570817
2014-12-31    1.481655
2015-12-31   -1.582277
2016-12-31    0.443544
2017-12-31   -1.296233
2018-12-31    0.479207
2019-12-31   -1.484178
2020-12-31    0.044787
Freq: A-DEC, Name: Series, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.resample` takes an offset parameter, subtracting the days left till the end of current year should to the trick. Something like:

```
ts.resample('A', loffset=today - date(today.year, 12, 31)).ffill()

2010-06-06    0.790428
2011-06-06    1.518362
2012-06-06    0.150378
2013-06-06    0.570817
2014-06-06    1.481655
2015-06-06   -1.582277
2016-06-06    0.443544
2017-06-06   -1.296233
2018-06-06    0.479207
2019-06-06   -1.484178
2020-06-06    0.044787
Name: Series, dtype: float64
```

Not sure how it behaves with leap days though, but it's not clear from your question how it should (i.e. what happens if today is feb 29?)

Comment: Thanks filippo! That's what i was looking for.